# Dojo grid gets refreshed when F12 is pressed

Tags: datagrid, dojo, firebug

I am using a Dojo grid where I am using many widgets like buttons, textboxes etc. Whenever I try to debug using <kbd>F12</kbd> or open Firebug (in Mozilla), the whole datagrid is refreshed. Can someone help me in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the Dgrid source and yes, Dgrid could repopulate the grid when resizing your browser. And if you think about, it does make sense: the viewport of the dgrid determines which items are shown, and which are destroyed (if you use `OnDemandGrid`).

You could disable it by creating your own Grid widget which extends `OnDemandGrid` (or any other grid class you're are using), and then overrule the `resize` method.
Just don't call `this.inherit(arguments)` and you're good to go.
Another way to go is to play around with the constructor parameters of Dgrid:

https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid

Comment: When the Dgrid reacts to the `resize` event, you could also open Firebug detached using Ctrl+F12, so it doesn't influence the window size.